# System freezing constantly; almost every time when starting a Java program

Tags: 12.04, java, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I've a brand new i7-3770 with 8gb RAM machine with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04.

As soon as I finished installing I realized the system was freezing often.

After digging a little on some forumns, I switched to kernel 3.3.6-030306-generic (it was 3.2.0-23), which did reduced the frequency of freezes, but hasn't eliminated it.

BTW: I have a Windows 7 boot, and the machine runs very well on it ==> so I discarded any hardware problems

Most of the freezes (but not all of them) occurs when I start a java proccess, like Eclipse or vuze.

Almost every time I start a java process I get a freeze tough.

Any help will be much aprreciated.

PS: I don't have any expirience in debugging problems like this, please guide me in how to obtain the necessary info and logs.

Logs:

Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_05" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Here's a copy of /var/log/kern.log reporting the freezing moment: (seems hw, but ok on Windows 7)

```
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.779998] ata1: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780017] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0002 action 0xe frozen
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780028] ata1.00: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780030] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780033] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:00:28:55:ec/00:00:00:00:00/e5 tag 0 dma 131072 in 
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780034]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error) 
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780035] ata1.00: status: { DRDY } 
Jul 31 21:20:35 ubuntu kernel: [  380.780042] ata1.00: hard resetting link 
Jul 31 21:20:36 ubuntu kernel: [  381.501535] ata1.01: hard resetting link 
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.526103] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.681602] ata1.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320) 
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.681613] ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0) 
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.729792] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.730009] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jul 31 21:20:37 ubuntu kernel: [  382.730018] ata1: EH complete 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524738] ata1: lost interrupt (Status 0x50) 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524756] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0002 action 0xe frozen 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524759] ata1.00: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch } 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524761] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524764] ata1.00: cmd  c8/00:d0:60:56:26/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 106496 in 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524765]          res  40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x14 (ATA bus error) 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524766] ata1.00: status: { DRDY } 
Jul 31 21:21:54 ubuntu kernel: [  459.524773] ata1.00: hard resetting link 
Jul 31 21:21:55 ubuntu kernel: [  460.246699] ata1.01: hard resetting link 
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.271757] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0) 
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.427342] ata1.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.427357] ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.475625] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.475878] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Jul 31 21:21:56 ubuntu kernel: [  461.475884] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: Please check if your harddisk has bad sectors using Disk Utility, either fomr your current installation or from a live cd.

If this is the case, it is strongly advised you make a back-up of your data as soon as possible and replace the harddisk.